# Dynamic Partionitioning in TazyGrid Cluster

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, distributed

When adding a new server or removing one, does TazyGrid (Open Source) partitions data at runtime or do we have to pre-plan & do some pre-deployement strategies ?

If some pre-deployment planning is required, can some one please link to any resources?

Answer (score 1):

Yes [TayzGrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) is completely dynamic and no pre-palnning is required.

Simply add a node to the cluster or remove it & data balancing will be done automatically.

- Peer to Peer Dynamic Cluster
- Runtime Discovery within Cluster
- Runtime Discovery by Clients
- Failover Support: Add/Remove Servers at Runtime

and more from [TayzGrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/dynamic-clustering.html) website

> Data distribution map: The data distribution map is provided only if the caching topology is Partitioned Cache or Partition-Replica Cache. **This information is useful for clients to determine the location of data in the cluster.** The client can therefore directly access the data from the cache server. The data distribution map is provided in two cases:
>
> - (1) at the time of the client’s connection to the server and
> - (2) **if when any change occurs in the partitioning map because a new server has been added or removed from the cluster.**